# Comparison Logic Error with Economic data - Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, compare, illegalargumentexception, compareto

I know I have some problem in my compareTo method, but not sure where..

Here's the data I'm trying to sort:

I'm looking at many .txt files (each around 20,000 lines) where each line has a single point of data. I am extracting a fiscal year (formatted YYYYqX, where X is 1-4 for fiscal quarter) and storing it as a String. I am also extracting an industry code (six-digit integer) and a price index (stored as a double). This is stored in a DataPoint object.

I want the output to be three columns, one of fiscal year, one of industry code, and one of price index. I want the data formatted so that the fiscal years are in order (1991q1, 1991q2,..., 1992q1, etc.), with the industry codes ordered in least to greatest value. So, the fiscal year column will have many 1991q1 entries for each industry code with a price index at that quarter. Then, when all industry codes for 1991q1 have been exhausted, then all the industry codes for 1991q2 will be listed, etc.

To accomplish this, I build my DataPoint compareTo method as follows:

```
public int compareTo(DataPoint p) {
    int fiscalResult = compareFiscal(p.getFiscalQuarter());
    if (fiscalResult > 0) {
        return fiscalResult;
    } else if (fiscalResult < 0) {
        return fiscalResult;
    } else {
        if (sectorCode > 0) {
            if (sectorCode > p.getSectorCode()) {
                return sectorCode - p.getSectorCode();
            }
            else if (sectorCode < p.getSectorCode()){
                return p.getSectorCode() - sectorCode;
            }
            else {
                return 0; // Should never happen
            }
        }
        else if (industryCode > 0) {
            if (industryCode > p.getIndustryCode()) {
                return industryCode - p.getIndustryCode();
            }
            else if (industryCode < p.getIndustryCode()) {
                return p.getIndustryCode() - industryCode;
            }
            else {
                return 0; // Should never happen
            }
        }
        // These should never be reached
        else if (p.getSectorCode() > 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (p.getIndustryCode() > 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

where the compareFiscal(String) method is just:

```
public int compareFiscal(String otherFiscal) {
    return fiscalQuarter.compareTo(otherFiscal);
}
```

fiscalQuarter is the name of the String variable containing the YYYYqX fiscal year.

When I said industry code earlier, there will actually either be a sector code (which is a four-digit integer) or an industry code (six-digit integer). A DataPoint will not have both (the one it doesn't have is initialized to 0), so that is the check for sectorCode or industryCode's value in the compareTo method.

I can sort a list of these points in one file without problem, but then at the end of my program I take all the data points from every file and put them into a new ArrayList (two lists, one for sector codes and one for industry codes. At no point are sector and industry codes sorted together), and call Collections.sort on this list. This is the point that throws the error.

Here is one point I am trying to call the Collections.sort method (for the industry list, an identical one is used for the sector list). A DataList is just another object that represents one file, containing two lists, one of all sector DataPoints and one of all industry DataPoints. The List of DataLists just has all of the DataLists created from every file. I don't think it illuminates anything, but just for relevance:

```
public static List<DataPoint> formatIndustryData(List<DataList> dataLists) {
    List<DataPoint> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataList list : dataLists) {
        data.addAll(list.getIndustryPoints());
    }
    Collections.sort(data);
    return data;
}
```

Can anyone see where my logic goes wrong in the compareTo method?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that there will never be a point, if the fiscal year is different, that we get a sector/industry code that is equal to another. (e.g. there is never two price indices for the same sector code at the same fiscal year, because that wouldn't make much sense).

Furthermore, at no point are DataPoints with industry values compared to DataPoints with sector values - they are stored in separate lists, and only compared and sorted among each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems incomplete.

If sectorCode of `this` instance > 0, you compare by sectorCode, but you don't handle the case where p.sectorCode <= 0.

Similarly, if industryCode of `this` instance > 0, you compare by industryCode, but you don't handle the case where p.industryCode <= 0.

You should decide which of the two properties - sectorCode and industryCode - takes precedence.

Suppose object A has sectorCode 5 and industryCode 0.
Object B has sectorCode 0 and industryCode 6.

A.compareTo(B) returns 1
B.compareTo(A) also returns 1

This breaks the contract of compareTo, since A>B and B>A can't both be true.

If you want to compare by sectorCode first, your code should look like :

```
    if (sectorCode > 0) {
        if (sectorCode > p.getSectorCode()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else if (p.getSectorCode() > 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (industryCode > 0) {
        if (industryCode > p.getIndustryCode()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else if (p.getIndustryCode() > 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0; // Should never happen
    }
```

In addition, you should probably return 0 if `industryCode == p.getIndustryCode()` (when both are positive) or `sectorCode == p.getSectorCode()` (when both are positive).

Comment: There is never a repeat of a sector/industry code at the same fiscal year. I didn't mention that, I apologize. So, if the fiscal year is equal, then I compare the sector/industry codes, and they will never be the same.

Comment: @eugene1832 But what if for the same fiscal year, one object has only sectorCode and the other only industryCode? Isn't that possible?

Comment: Ah I see what you're asking. So a DataPoint has either a sector code or an industry code, and are stored in two separate lists, one of DataPoints with sector values, and one of DataPoints with industry values. Those lists never merge together, so they are only sorting among sector values or industry values, not both.

The formatIndustryData method I included at the bottom, for example, is sorting all of the DataPoints containing industry values from all of the files. There is another method that does this for all of the DataPoints with sector values.

Comment: @eugene1832 Regardless of whether you think it should work for the specific lists you are trying to sort, the contract is very specific - `The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y.` Since you are breaking the contract, you can't expect it to work.

Comment: I made changes to the compareTo method and edited my question to reflect that, but I'm still being told my comparison method breaks the general contract.

Comment: @eugene1832 You still have a problem with the order of the conditions. If should be `if (sectorCode>0){} else if (p.getSectorCode()>0){} else if (industryCode>0) {} else if (p.getIndustryCode()>0){} else {}`